# How do I move an SVG group with CSS keyframes?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to move SVG elements across their container using CSS keyframes.

If I had just a `<circle />`, I could simply use the `cx` / `cy` properties in the keyframe definition. But what if I had an arbitrary group (`<g />`)? A group doesn't have `cx` / `cy`, and it seems that I have to define a unit (like `px`) if I wanted to use CSS' `transform: translate(x,y)`.

MWE (how do I animate the `bar` group?):

```css
svg {
padding: 5px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.foo {
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: moveFoo;
}

.bar {
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: moveBar;
}

@keyframes moveFoo {
from {
cx: 10;
cy: 10;
}
to {
cx: 90;
cy: 90;
}
}

/* how to define this? */
@keyframes moveBar { }
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle class="foo" r="5" fill="red" />
<g class="bar" transform="translate(90 10)">
    <circle r="5" fill="blue" />
    <text
        y="1"
        text-anchor="middle"
        fill="white"
        font-family="monospace"
        font-size="5">
    AB
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems that I have to define a unit (like px) if I wanted to use
>   CSS' transform: translate(x,y).

Yes, it's true, you do.

But that won't be an issue, if you have already declared a `viewbox` attribute in the `<svg>` element.

If you have declared a `viewbox`, `1px` will represent 1 viewbox unit.

**Working Example:**

```css
svg {
padding: 5px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.foo {
fill: red;
transform: translate(10px, 10px);
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: moveFoo;
}

.bar {
transform: translate(90px, 10px);
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: moveBar;
}

.bar circle {
fill: blue;
}

.bar text {
fill: white;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 5px;
text-anchor: middle;
}

@keyframes moveFoo {
   0% {transform: translate(10px, 10px);}
  50% {transform: translate(90px, 90px);}
 100% {transform: translate(10px, 10px);}
}

@keyframes moveBar {
   0% {transform: translate(90px, 10px);}
  50% {transform: translate(10px, 90px);}
 100% {transform: translate(90px, 10px);}
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<circle class="foo" r="5" />

<g class="bar">
  <circle r="5" />
  <text y="1">AB</text>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I wasn't aware about the relation to the viewbox unit :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`animateTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) to do this:

```css
svg {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle class="foo" r="5" fill="red" />
<g id="bar" transform="translate(90 10)">

    <circle r="5" fill="blue" />
    <text
        y="1"
        text-anchor="middle"
        fill="white"
        font-family="monospace"
        font-size="5">
    AB
</text>
</g>
<animateTransform xlink:href="#bar" 
    attributeName="transform" 
    type="translate"
    from="90,10" to="90,90"
    dur="2" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice, I really need to take another look at SVGs and start learning effects like `<animateTransform />`. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `@keyframes` instead of animating the cx and cy attributes you have to animate from `transform:translate(0,0)` to `transform:translate(90px,90px)` (for example.)

Otherwise Temani Afif's answer is perfectly valid.
`

```css
svg {
padding: 5px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.foo {
transform:translate(0,0);
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: moveFoo;
}

.bar {
transform:translate(0,0);
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: moveBar;
}



@keyframes moveFoo {
from {
transform:translate(0,0)
}
to {
transform:translate(90px,90px)
}
}

/* how to define this? */
@keyframes moveBar { 
from {
transform:translate(0,0)
}
to {
transform:translate(90px,90px)
}
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle class="foo" r="5" fill="red" />
<g class="bar" >
    <circle r="5" fill="blue" cx="10" cy="10" />
    <text
        x="10"
        y="11"
        text-anchor="middle"
        fill="white"
        font-family="monospace"
        font-size="5">
  AB
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```